# Incorrect validation on ssl

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2

I was trying to set up ssl using certbot. My webserver is nginx. when I run the command "sudo ./certbot-auto certonly" I enter my domain, which I purchased using netfirms. The domain is pointed to my amazon ec2 instance( public ip). I get  this error " Type:   unauthorized Detail: Incorrect validation certificate for TLS-SNI-01 challenge." Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it's the apache plugin that you are using.

The way the apache plugin works is that it adds a temporary  with a "fake" certificate and SNI hostname that solves the TLS-SNI-01 challenge. Since this server has multiple IP addresses, I'm not certain if the apache plugin is capable of determining the correct IP address to listen on for this temporary . I haven't seen any success stories that explicitly mention this scenario, at least.

Your best bet might be to switch to the webroot plugin, which works by writing files to your existing DocumentRoot. If you'd like to continue using the automatic apache configuration while using the webroot authenticator, try something like this:

```
./certbot-auto --authenticator webroot --installer apache -w /var/www/html -d example.com
```

Comment: @error2007s- can i use this with nginx or do i need the apache webserver

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - only when trying to update an existing key.

What I noticed was that the validation error said the it found a certificate that had all the other domain names in it that I had already requested in the certificate before.

Why does the validator see the previous certificate?

From the logs it seems to set up a new VirtualHost for each domain in the new cert in order to verify that the server is the one pointed to by the DNS. Validation requests to these mini VirtualHosts are not working correctly if it is seeing the existing cert with every domain in it - I though "my virtualhosts set up is somehow causing a problem!"

I thought maybe because I have a wildcard in my virtualHost it is somehow getting picked up before the mini temporary VirtualHosts.

I had named my existing hosts with 3 digit numeric prefixes so that I could carefully order them given that Apache said it processes .conf files in alphabetical order. This would mean they would get processed BEFORE any other .conf files starting with a letter.

I renamed my .conf files by adding a 'c' prefix before the number and now it appears at though it's working because it got passed the verification phase at least now - except now I have exceeded by 20 key requests for the week so I can't complete the process just yet!! Doh!